# TransferSpreadsheet - Run time error 4298 - Specify Range

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to import a tab from an excel file into a table in access using TransferSpreadsheet.
My code works fine until I try and specify a range on the tab I want to bring in.

When I include "A:AH" in the code I get the following error: Run time error 4298
"an expression you entered is the wrong data type for one of the arguments"

I've googled the error however all examples of specifying a range have it in the below format, so I really don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Accounts_Listing", path, 1, "Summary!", "A:AH"
```

Any help would be appreciated, as the range needs to be specified as some of the files uploaded bring in blank columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transferspreadsheet) for `TransferSpreadsheet` there is **no** argument for sheet name. You need to amend your range argument to also include the sheet name

---

### The parameters for `TransferSpreadsheet` are as follows:

1. `TransferType` *(acImport)*
2. `SpreadsheetType` *(12)*
3. `TableName` *(Accounts_Listing)*
4. `FileName` *(Path)*
5. `HasFieldNames` *(1)*
6. `Range` *("Summary!A:AH")*

---

Notice that there is no argument for sheet name which is what you are doing. In short, your sheet name is being evaluated as a range which is consistent with your error. Combining all of this together, you should have

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 12, "Accounts_Listing", path, 1, "Summary!A:AH"
```